# Is it possible to have a Lottie json referencing an image url instead of providing a path to the downloaded file?

Tags: lottie, after-effects

Is it possible to have the Lottie json reference a url to the image instead of location of the image?

Will something like this work? If not is there a way or is this not possible in Lottie?

```
    {
    "v": "5.6.3",
    "fr": 30,
    "ip": 0,
    "op": 300,
    "w": 1920,
    "h": 1080,
    "nm": "test11",
    "ddd": 0,
    "assets": [
        {
            "id": "image_0",
            "w": 2560,
            "h": 1600,
            "p": "https://images.pexels.com/photos/7174/summer-grass.jpg", <- is something like this possible
            "e": 0
        }
    ],
........
```

Answer (score 0):

Figured out that we can actually encode the image as part of the lottie json file as below. This can done using After Effects extensions like bodymovin.

```
    {
    "v": "5.9.0",
    "fr": 29.9700012207031,
    "ip": 126.000005132085,
    "op": 451.000018369607,
    "w": 360,
    "h": 800,
    "nm": "Initial Screen",
    "ddd": 0,
    "assets": [
        {
            "id": "image_0",
            "w": 125,
            "h": 201,
            "u": "",
            "p": "data:image/png;base64,iVBORw........", <- encoded image here
            "e": 1
        },
        {
     ...
```